# Efficient and practical way to generalize struct access?

Tags: c++, templates, class, struct

I have the following:

```
Struct A {
   char a;
   char b[10];
   int c;
   float d;
}

Struct B {
   float d;
   char b[10];
   char a;
   int c;
   bool e;
}
```

and I want to make a generic function that accepts struct A or B to access elements like:

```
void SetD(A a, float f) { a.d = f; }
```

There will be many different Structs (most with the same elements) and many functions to operate on them.

I'm trying to generalize the access so I don't have to copy each method into each Struct resulting in duplicate code.  Not sure if `instanceof` or templates would be best here.  Any ideas on how to implement this elegantly?  Let me know if I can provide more clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
template< typename T > void setD( T &t, float f ) { t.d = f; }
```

---

**Note** that the `struct` keyword is lowercase, and that structs require a semicolor `;` after the closing bracket.

Comment: +1.  You could also templatise f template < class T, class U > void setD( T& t, const U& f ) to make it even more general

Comment: Well, if you're going to make it uber-generic, there's also `template < class T, class U , class V> void setAnything( T& t, U T::* u, const V& v ) { t.*u = v; }` but at a certain point this becomes silly.